# Twitter Bootstrap - Dynamically Add/Remove Tabs and Tab Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Thanks in advance for any and all input/help/advice...

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap tabs to organize some information. The tabs will be located on a form page, and each tab will consist of a "contact form", in which the user can add multiple contacts to this page prior to submitting the whole form.

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#contact_01" data-toggle="tab">Joe Smith</a><span>x</span></li>
        <li><a href="#contact_02" data-toggle="tab">Molly Lewis</a><span>x</span> </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="add-contact" data-toggle="tab">+ Add Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="contact_01">Contact Form: Joe Smith</div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="contact_02">Contact Form: Molly Lewis</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Full code here: http://jsfiddle.net/Harlow/zQnck/34/

I'm trying to mimic the functionality of jQuery UI's "simple manipulation" example of tabs.
(http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#manipulation)

What I currently have will add a new tab, but I want to be able to add a new, unique tab with it's own ID (continuing from the code, like "contact_01, contact_02, etc.") by clicking on the "+ Add New Contact" which will always be the last tab, but not actually have it's own tab content pane. On the other side of dynamically adding content, I want to be able to delete it by click the small "x" on each tab.

--EDIT--

Just to clarify, the jQuery example trigger's a modal upon clicking "New Tab". For my purposes, I just want to create a new tab without inputting the tab name or content (the content will always be the same contact form, and I'm fine with the tab name being the same as the newly generated ID - I will have it automatically update to the contact's name later.)

Comment: For starters, use `$(this).closest('li').before()` to append new tabs instead of `$('.nav-tabs').append.append()`. I'm working on the rest now

Comment: @Harlow your fiddle isn't working

Answer (score 13, accepted):

EDIT: I reproduced the original fiddle as best as I could as both fiddles died.

New fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dogoku/KdPdZ/2/

```
$(".nav-tabs").on("click", "a", function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).tab('show');
    })
    .on("click", "span", function () {
        var anchor = $(this).siblings('a');
        $(anchor.attr('href')).remove();
        $(this).parent().remove();
        $(".nav-tabs li").children('a').first().click();
    });

    $('.add-contact').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(".nav-tabs").children().length; //think about it ;)
        $(this).closest('li').before('<li><a href="#contact_'+id+'">New Tab</a><span>x</span></li>');         
        $('.tab-content').append('<div class="tab-pane" id="contact_'+id+'">Contact Form: New Contact '+id+'</div>');
});
```

Note that I removed the hover function and instead used css

```
.nav-tabs > li:hover > span {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: this is fantastic, thank you! i completely forgot about .children(). now as far as having the ability to delete tabs, what do you suggest?

Comment: seriously, many thanks. this is perfect. i can finally stop tearing my hair out over it. appreciate all of the work!

Answer (score 2):

Dogoku's jsfiddle seems to be 404, so I put together a quick jsfiddle of the solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/xQ3f5/

I updated this to stop the 'active' class being applied to the +Add Contact tab element, as that doesn't correspond to any of the tab elements. I'd also suggest switching the active tab to the newly created one. Here's the javascript:

```
$(".nav-tabs").on("click", "a", function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
    if(this.id == "add-contact"){return false;}
      $(this).tab('show');
    })
    .on("click", "span", function () {
        var anchor = $(this).siblings('a');
        $(anchor.attr('href')).remove();
        $(this).parent().remove();
        $(".nav-tabs li").children('a').first().click();
    });

    $('#add-contact').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(".nav-tabs").children().length; //think about it ;)
        $(this).closest('li').before('<li id="contact_tab_'+id+'"><a href="#contact_'+id+'">New Tab</a></li>');         
        $('.tab-content').append('<div class="tab-pane" id="contact_'+id+'">Contact Form: New Contact '+id+'</div>');
        $("#contact_tab_"+id+" a").tab('show');
});
```

Comment: nice. fiddles tend to die off. that's why SO makes you post your code when they detect a fiddle link