# Switch between stacked modals

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I currently have a few stacked modals open on my screen. I've created a basic [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VNfLE/) for this.

They are stacked by:

```
#myModal{
  top: 0% ;
}
#myModal2{
  top: 5% ;
}
#myModal3{
  top: 10% ;
}
#myModal4{
  top: 15% ;
}
```

What I want is to be able to click between the open modals. For example. When all four are up, I want to be able to click on the visible part of Modal 1 and for Modal 1 to come to the front. Or (if that can't happen), I want to have a button that will let me bring Modal 1 to the front.

So far, I can't find anything in bootstrap that lets me do this.

Comment: Have you looked at binding a click event to the modal window to adjust the z-index property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not been able to try this in a fiddle, but you should create a click event on all elements with class `.modal-dialog` and in the event handler set all elements of `.modal` to have a certain z-index and then set the modal of what was clicked using `this` to be a higher z-index.

Something like:

```
$(".modal-dialog").click (function() {
      var modalSelected = $(this).parent();     
      $(".modal").each(function() {
          var idx = $(this).length;
          $(this).css('z-index', 1040 + (10 * idx));
      });
      modalSelected.css('z-index',1500);
 });
```

The problem you may have is that one large modal may completely obscure all other modal dialogs. Did you think about possibly [using tabs instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349281/twitter-bootstrap-dynamically-add-remove-tabs-and-tab-content)?

Comment: I think the z-index is the right way to implement this. We ended up switching the design some. But thanks for the answer!